# r shiny navbarpage keep navigation bar at top of screen

Tags: r, shiny

In R shiny, if you had a really long single page, is there anyway to keep the navigation bar (from`navbarPage`) at the top of the screen even while you're scrolling down?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You should follow the navbarPage reference regarding this:

[Shiny reference: navbarPage](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/navbarPage.html)

Bottomline: you have to argue the position argument of navbarPage():

```
    navbarPage(title, ..., position = "fixed-top")
```

"fixed-top" will pin the navbar to the top.